# v-for is rendering my list in one row with many columns instead of one column with many rows

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want my list to be rendered like this:

1. A
2. B
3. C

Right now its being rendered like this:
1: A 2: B 3: C

Heres the code:

## Todos:

```
    <input type="text" class = "todo" placeholder = "Next Item" v-on:keyup.enter="addItem()">
    <ol>
      <li v-for="(todo, index) in todos" class ="todos">
       {{index}}: {{ todo.text }}
      </li>
    </ol>
```

Heres the javascript portion:

```
addItem(){
  var text = event.target.value;
  this.todos.push({text, done: false, id: Date.now()})
  text = '';
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Inspect the page and see if separate `li` elements are being created, if so, then it is your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure why yours is displaying any different, but here's a rough example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      todos: ['derek', 'was', 'here'],
      newTodo: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addTodo() {
      this.todos.push(this.newTodo);
      this.newTodo = '';
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <input v-model="newTodo" />
    <button @click="addTodo">add</button>
    <ol>
      <li v-for="(todo, index) in todos" :key="index">{{todo}}</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

The only other thing I can think of is that you have some special CSS styling set that's causing the issue.